# Linea pro connect issue in iTouch

Tags: barcode, ipod, linea-pro

Hi am working on scanning barcodes through iOS device (iPod touch) using linea pro case. 
I just downloaded the linea pro demo project and the sdk from here
 http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/Linea-Pro-iPhone-SDK/8/102

Am trying to run the demo project on my iPod touch but after running on the device i get this message repeatedly ***NSPortTimeoutException - Linea not connected!

If you have any idea what is wrong please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: I assume you have connected the iPod touch to the Linea Pro case? I've done the same thing and the demo app works without any modifications.

Comment: Yes Phil have connected the device to my iPodtouch,any ways got the issuesolfe.it was something to do with an older version of sdk which works only till leine4

Answer (score 1):

The linea cannot connect to usb & the scanner at the same time. Disconnect the cable, and try again. I'm pretty sure now it will connect!